# Create Office 365 / Azure AD federated user using Graph API

Tags: office365, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-active-directory

I have been trying to create an office 365 federated user using Azure AD Graph API however it is always creating Cloud identity instead of "Synced with Active Directory". Here is a post query I am hitting;

Request to: https://graph.windows.net/{0}/users?api-version=1.5

{0}: Tenancy Name

{"accountEnabled": "true","displayName": "James","mailNickname": "CloudIdentity","usageLocation": "GB","passwordProfile": { "password" : "Temp@123", "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": "false" },"userPrincipalName": "xyz@cn.cloudidentity.in","immutableId": "nEmSERX0EeaAwwANOrGMiQ=="}

It is creating user successfully but as a said above, its creating Cloud Identity, what should I do to make it a federated user?

here are the two articles I followed but both are saying Immutable ID is the key which is already being passed:

https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/office-365-custom-provisioning
https://yorkporc.wordpress.com/2014/08/03/enter-a-post-title/

NOTE: when I am doing login with one of the federated user, it gives this error:

**Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in
Please try again in a few minutes. If this doesn't work, you might want to contact your admin and report the following error: 80048163.**

Also the federated domain is subdomain;

**cn.cloudidentity.in**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much @Fei Xue, You are right. However I didnt want to sync password back so which is fine. And it is still showing as cloud identity however the federation is working. The issue in my case was the IssuerID in the SAML Assertion being returned from Identity Provider. That was NOT matching with the one configured in office 365 domain. As soon as we fixed it, it started working fine...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> > I have been trying to create an office 365 federated user using Azure AD Graph API however it is always creating Cloud identity instead of "Synced with Active Directory".

This is expected behavior. The Graph API does not handle the user sync part. To make the user create on the cloud sync back into the on-premises directory, we can config it in the Azure connect using option feature – writeback like figure below:
[image]

More detail about integrating your on-premises identities with Azure Active Directory, please refer to [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/).